# More Efficient MySQL Subquery?

Tags: mysql, subquery, group-concat, having-clause

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a query with a subquery. Follow along, if you will:

SAMPLE DATA:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    user_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(64),
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id)
);

CREATE TABLE cars {
    car_id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_id INT(10),
    caryear YEAR(4),
    carmaker VARCHAR(32),
    carmodel VARCHAR(32),
    PRIMARY KEY (car_id, user_id)
    FOREIGN KEY(`user_id`) references users(`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;    

INSERT INTO users (user_id, name) VALUES (1,'Bob'),(2,'John'),(3,'Sally');
INSERT INTO cars (user_id, caryear, carmaker, carmodel) VALUES
(1,'2004','Audi','A4'),
(1,'2006','Toyota','Camry'),
(1,'2014','Jeep','CJ'),
(2,'1998','Acura','CL'),
(2,'2014','Honda','Accord'),
(3,'2011','Jeep','Rubicon')
```

Okay, so if I want to get a list of users and their cars, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  username,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CarYear,' ',CarMaker,' ',CarModel))
   FROM cars
   WHERE cars.user_id = users.user_id
  ) AS Cars
FROM users;
```

But how can I get a list of users that own a 2004-2014 Jeep, for instance?

I've come up with this, but **I'm sure there is a more elegant approach**:

```
SELECT
  user_id,
  username,
  (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(CarYear,' ',CarMaker,' ',CarModel))
   FROM cars
   WHERE cars.user_id = users.user_id
   AND CarMaker = 'Jeep'
   AND CarYear BETWEEN 2004 AND 2014
  ) AS Cars
FROM users
HAVING Cars is not null;
```

**The problem with this solution is that it does not show the other cars owned by people who own 2004-2014 Jeeps.**

Any advice?

Comment: note  GROUP_CONCAT has an limit of 1024 bytes.. like mentioned in the documentation http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat most likely this is causing your problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show the users and a list of all their cars, for any user who owns a Jeep 2004-2014:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  u.username,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(c.CarYear,' ',c.CarMaker,' ',c.CarModel)) AS Cars
FROM users u
INNER JOIN cars c USING (user_id)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM cars
  WHERE c.CarMaker = 'Jeep' 
    AND c.CarYear BETWEEN 2004 AND 2014) AS j USING (user_id)
GROUP BY u.user_id, u.username;
```

Comment: This is exactly perfect. I had to rotate my brain 90 degrees to understand it. What is the "AS j" there for?

Comment: @pbarney, in SQL any derived table subquery requires a table alias.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is a many-to-many relationship, you actually need to break `cars` into two tables. The first table will be the same as `cars` is now, except remove `user_id` from it. The second table (call it `user_car`) has two columns: `user_id` and `car_id`.

Once you do that, the query is simple:

```
SELECT user_id FROM user_car WHERE car_id IN
    (SELECT car_id FROM cars
   WHERE CarMaker = 'Jeep'
   AND CarYear BETWEEN 2004 AND 2014
  )
```

If you need to pull data straight from `users`, expand the query to:

```
SELECT user_id, username FROM users WHERE user_id IN
  (SELECT user_id FROM user_car WHERE car_id IN
    (SELECT car_id FROM cars
   WHERE CarMaker = 'Jeep'
   AND CarYear BETWEEN 2004 AND 2014
  ))
```

Comment: That's more normalized, but I'm dealing with a limited data set. The `cars` table doesn't contain every possible year,make,model combination available. With this in mind, would you still recommend it?

Comment: There are very few cases where normalizing doesn't make sense, and I don't think this is one of them. The existence of a car type isn't dependent on whether anyone drives it, so giving the cars their own table makes sense. I also doubt you'd take any noticeable performance hit.

Answer (score 0):

INNER JOIN would do the trick.

```
SELECT u.* FROM users u
INNER JOIN cars c ON c.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE CarMaker = 'Jeep' AND CarYear BETWEEN 2004 AND 2014
```

[image: inner join]